# Azure functions storage recommandation

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using Azure functions as micro services. I have 7 functions apps running in an App Service. What is the recommandation about the storage (AzureWebJobsStorage & AzureWebJobsDashboard) ?

Should I create 2 storage accounts (1 for AzureWebJobsStorage & 1 for AzureWebJobsDashboard) for each function app or can I share ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to have them share it.

Additional related trivia:

1. AzureWebJobsDashboard is fine to share across multiple WebJobs / FunctionApps. However, Functions is moving over to be fully integrated with AppInsights and doesn't need this setting anymore. Here's a tutorial with more information: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/azure-functions-now-integrated-with-application-insights/
2. AzureWebJobsStorage  provides the default storage for [Blob], [Table], [Queue] bindings. This can be overridden with the [StorageAccount] attribute.